# Sending Email using java timeout exception

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail, connection-timeout

I am trying to send email to gmail using java. I am using this code.

```
final String username = "xyz@gmail.com";
        final String password = "**********";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port","587");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password);
        }
        });



            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xyz@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,newInternetAddress("abcdef@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("First email to using java");
            message.setContent("<h:body style =background-color:white> This is a test mail sent using java" + "</body>","text/html;  charset=utf-8");
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Message Sent");
```

But When i run the above code it shows follwoing error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;
```

I have an Internet connection which uses proxy server and requires authentication. Is this error because of Proxy or there is some problem in my code. Please tell me how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's because of your proxy server.

- [How do I configure JavaMail to work through my proxy server?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#proxy)

  the above link expired: check this link
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#proxy

Comment: The link provided says  **JavaMail does not support access through a HTTP proxy web server.**  that means it is impossible to send email on a http proxy server using java or there is some way?

Comment: If all you have is an http proxy server, you can't connect through it directly using JavaMail.  That said, it's not **impossible**.  HTTP does support a "tunneling" capability that could be used, but it's not supported by any of the underlying java.net classes that JavaMail uses, and JavaMail doesn't have direct support for it.  You may be able to do it indirectly using programs like [Corkscrew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corkscrew_%28program%29) mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

JavaMail can't use a web proxy server directly, although it can use a SOCKS proxy server. If you only have a web proxy server, programs like Corkscrew can help.

You can setup SOCKS proxy server in JavaMail with like this:

```
Properties p = System.getProperties();
p.setProperty("proxySet","true");
p.setProperty("socksProxyHost","192.168.1.1");
p.setProperty("socksProxyPort","1234");
```